# Jquery-ui selectmenu doesn't play well with jqgrid js

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using a jquery-ui select along with a theme and the jqgrid JS, however the options for the select do not drop down under the select's button. The appear in the top left of the browser. How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: You can expect help if you put a demo. You problem seems to be specific and related with css settings

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the reply. I have now resolved the issue. It seems for some reason that the jquery-ui theme that I had downloaded had issues. I pointed to the CDN for that theme and it is working great now.